# What is a dns glue check?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to troubleshoot issue with my DNS. I ran a report on dnsinspect.com

> FAIL: Found differences between information provided by your
>   authoritative name servers and glue provided by the parent name
>   servers: ns1.domain.com. @parent=[xx.xx.xx.yy] @ns=[xx.xx.xx.xy] The
>   glue provided by the parent name servers has to match the data
>   provided by the authoritative name servers.

I'm using windows server as a DNS server. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Talk to whoever runs the parent that's providing the bad glue. Make sure they know the correct IP address for any nameservers inside your domain.

Answer (score 1):

A domain `example.com` needs to have identical NS records listed in the "parent" zone – `com` in this case. If those NS records point to servers *in* the `example.com` domain, you'd basically need to ask those servers to tell you their own addresses... To avoid this kind of loop, the parent domain will also have A/AAAA records of those nameservers. so as soon as you query the `com` servers for `example.com/NS` they'll automatically send you the data of `ns1.example.com/A` along with it. This is what "glue" records are.

In your case, the domains `com` and `example.com` have different entries for `ns1.example.com`, which can often cause great confusion even if it might not break things.

Go to the domain management interface, or otherwise contact your registrar, and make sure the "glue" or "delegation" addresses are identical to the ones in your own domain.